# Append numpy one dimensional arrays does not lead to a matrix

Tags: python, initialization, append, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to get a 2d array, by randomly generating its rows and appending

```
   import numpy as np
   my_nums =  np.array([])
    for i in range(100):
      x = np.random.rand(2, 1)
      my_nums = np.append(my_nums, np.array(x))
```

But I do not get what I want but instead get a 1d array.

What is wrong?
Transposing x did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by using `np.append(axis=0)` or `np.vstack`. This however requires the rows appended to have the same length as the rows already in the array.

You cannot use the same code to append a row with two values to an empty array, and to append a row to an already existing 2D array: numpy will throw a
`ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`.

You could initialize `my_nums` to work around this:

```
my_nums = np.random.rand(1, 2)
for i in range(99):
    x = np.random.rand(1, 2)
    my_nums = np.append(my_nums, x, axis=0)
```

Note the decrease in the range by one due to the initialization row. Also note that I changed the dimensions to (1, 2) to get actual row vectors.

Much easier than appending row-wise will of course be to create the array in the wanted final shape:

```
my_nums = np.random.rand(100, 2)
```